# Section Item : Get Section Name on Tap of Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Trying to get Name of Section, when I do tap on any of the Item of that particular Section.

I am following [this](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/) tutorials, where my UI data is divided into two parts: Section and Item(s)

Now for my knowledge I would like to see the name of Section (once I do tap on any of the Item)

For an example, I have 5 sections, where each of the section contains 5 Items itself and Let assume I have tapped on 4th Item of the Section 2nd

So How Do I know that, as you can see I am getting name of tapped Item, but on Tap I also want to get name of Section (which Item I just tapped) ?

```
public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ....

        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            .....

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the link you provided, you simply need to pass and store the section name in `SectionListAdapter` as below:

```
public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
    private Context mContext;
    private String mSectionName;

    public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, String sectionName, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
        mSectionName = sectionName;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

        SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

        holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView tvTitle;

        protected ImageView itemImage;


        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mSectionName +" : "+ tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        }

    }

}
```

Now in your `RecyclerViewDataAdapter` simply change the one line of initializing `SectionListDataAdapter` inside your `onBindViewHolder` as below:

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, sectionName, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


        itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;

        protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

        protected Button btnMore;



        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
            this.btnMore= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


        }

    }

}
```